# Put images on top of another img (the responsive mode)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I got a big problem:

I need to pot several images on top of another images. In non-responsive mode I would use:

```
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
```

and for the parent

```
    position: relative;
```

But I'm working on a responsive site with BootStrap 3 and this method breaks the layout.
Do you guys have some idea?

Note: the pictures must be "fluid" (with bootstrap class img-responsive) and all the pictures have the same ratio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this would pertain to your needs, but you could use an `img` tag inside of a `div` with the `background-image` property set. Something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="imageDiv">
    <img src="whatever.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imageDiv {
    background-image: url('something.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; /*or 'contain' depending on your needs*/
}
```